# See which element owns any specific pixel of a web page

Tags: html, css, dom, firebug

Sometimes I see some an unwanted border or another element in the web page and I have a lot of troubles identifying just to which element it belongs.

There may be many enclosed elements, any of which may or may not have the border in question, for example. Right now I have to go through each of them and check the border property of each, which takes a lot of effort.

So is there a way to see which element owns any given on-screen pixel with Firefox, Firebug, Chrome or any other web development tool?
I just want to point my mouse cursor at any pixel in question and see the corresponding element and/or rule.

There's usually an option to inspect any chosen element, but right-clicking on the border of an element and choosing to inspect the element doesn't seem to show the exact element the border of which was clicked.

Comment: The reason this received downvotes is that it's a request for a tool, library or other outside resource, which is not a request that StackOverflow is here to answer.  [Please see here on "How to ask".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  

It's also unclear exactly what you're asking.  The web inspector/Firebug are both very well-known tools which achieve exactly what you're looking for, and both should have been identifiable by a Google search.

Comment: Question found unclear, whether you are looking for a tool for debugging OR wan to know trick for debugging. Very unclear. I do agree with @JoshBurgess

Comment: Imagine you have a horizontal or vertical black line somewhere on a web page. I'm looking for a way to know where it came from. The element picker doesn't seem to be able to do that anywhere reliably - I get some element which has no direct connection to that black line - it may merely be sitting next to it, it may be a child to the element I'm looking for etc.

Comment: @dragonroot, I get it. You want to know where a stray line is coming from.  The element inspector is _still_ the best option for that, as it's interpreting how the browser is displaying your page and you're not going to get any closer to the source than something built into the browser itself.  This question would probably be better served as a _how do I debug?_ foray.

Comment: Sure! My point is, while any browser knows where that line comes from, I'm not very successful in pursuing one of them to tell me that, hence the question. Maybe there's a browser out there which would be more willing, or some specialized blink or gecko-based tool exactly to fulfill that purpose, which I don't know about.

Comment: This is a good question for Stack Overflow. The [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page declares that questions that ask for a tool recommendation are off-topic. This question does not ask exclusively for that. It's mainly about how to use specific tools: "Firefox, Firebug, Chrome." The Help Center page says that Stack Overflow is the right place to ask about "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element inspector *should* do the job. The only reason I could think of for why it fails is when the element in question is *covered* by another element. See example:

```css
#test-1 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
#test-1 >div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#test-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#test-2 > div {
  width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-1">
  <div>Inspect me</div>
</div>
<div id="test-2">
  <div>Obstructive element</div>
</div>
```

And the solution is simple: right-click on the element in question and click inspect element (zoom the page if necessary). If it is not the correct element, hit the del button on the keyboard. This removes the element you just selected. Repeat until necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I could think of is to use the "element picker" function which exists in any developer tool.

In Chrome it is a "magnifying glass" and in Firefox a "square with an arrow" - both at the top left.

Click to activate and move the cursor around the page to inspect. The respective element is highlighted.

So you should easily find the element you are looking for.

An example: [image]

Comment: It's not reliable. See my comment to the main question.

Comment: @dragonroot As elements may "overlap" or "shine through" there will be no way to 100% identify the respective element simply by moving the cursor over it on the screen. In such cases as you describe in your comment you have to walk through the DOM in the developer tool.

Comment: Post the link to the site you are talking about, and the pixel you are concerned about

Answer (score 0):

As far as browser functionality goes, there are two thoughts that come to mind:

1. The 'elements' tab of Chrome Developer Tools.  If you hover over elements within the tab, that area of the page will be highlighted, complete with a height/width tooltip.  (I do realize this is sort of the opposite of your use case, but it could still be useful).
2. Similarly, the Firefox page inspector has similar functionality.

It might be worth writing a small script to get the functionality you're looking for.  You might look into jQuery's `elementFromPoint`.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t8vapLwr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this chrome extension if you don't want to rely on the element picker.

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bblbgcheenepgnnajgfpiicnbbdmmooh
```

what it does is highlight the different elements on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand your problem. I have been thought it. So what i do is the following:

1. Obviously you can use the inspect tool which sometimes doesn't shows us what we exactly need.
2. You can use this chrome extension [Precise Element Picker Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/) and then select the specific element.

I am sure the 2nd option will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using "Inspect Element" on a border has always worked for me, but potentially this could help.

It was mentioned by [Sculper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389715/1266426), but you could do something really quick yourself using `document.elementFromPoint`.

Just copy and paste this into the console:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));
}, true);
```

Then you can click around the page to find the element in question.

In Chrome, Firefox, and Firebug, that outputs the element to the console, which you can then click (or for Chrome right-click and "Reveal in Elements Panel") to see it in the Elements Panel.

If you need clicking for navigation (for a single-page app or the like), you can simply change the event being captured to `mousemove` or `dblclick`.

Comment: or [elementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint)